# UIalertView dosen't call alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a class called MatchmakingServer has a method as following:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state
```

{

```
switch (state)
{
    case GKPeerStateAvailable:
        break;

    case GKPeerStateUnavailable:
        break;

        // A new client has connected to the server.
    case GKPeerStateConnected:
        if (_serverState == ServerStateAcceptingConnections)
        {
            if (![_connectedClients containsObject:peerID])
            {
                NSString *peerID2 =[self displayNameForPeerID:peerID];
                self.PeerId=peerID;
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops:("
                                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@ %@",@"device",peerID2,@"want to join your session"]
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];


                [_connectedClients addObject:peerID];
                NSLog(@"the orginal peerID %@",peerID);
                [self.delegate matchmakingServer:self clientDidConnect:peerID];
            }
        }
```

also

```
@interface MatchmakingServer : NSObject <GKSessionDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

**Any Ideas why alertView dosn't call the clickedButtonAtIndex**

Comment: Do you call `[alert show]` somewhere? And how did you declare `clickedButtonAtIndex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing the alert view on the screen, you're only initializing it. Insert

```
[alert show];
```

after the initialization code and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[alert show];` method and adopt `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your `UIViewController.h` file.